# How can I better convey the idea of "message sent"?

Tags: sketch-app, icon, symbols, mobile, mobile-first

Currently, I am designing a mobile screen where the user can send a message to their friends.

[image]

In order to show that their message has been sent, the upper right hand corner check-mark goes from black to a greyed out double check-mark (i.e. from a pressable button to a non-pressable icon).

However, I am not really that happy with this design – I feel that it is not intuitive enough. I am wondering what I can do to improve it and better convey the idea of "message sent" to the user.

**CLARIFICATION EDIT:**

*I have already used ✗ to represent "back/cancel", ✓ to represent "okay/confirm", and ✓✓ to represent "message read" - in other parts of my application design. Also this is not mean't to be a modal popup.*

Comment: The word "sent" in grey, unclickable.

Comment: Or change the black check mark to something else, like the paper plane or an arrow-based icon; then have that change into a check mark once the message is successfully sent.

Comment: @Scott I'm trying to avoid using actual words due to concerns with potential future localization issues. I want to stick with symbols.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I really like the paper airplane idea. But not the fact that it switches back into double check marks afterwards. If we represent the "before" with a paper plane, do you have any ideas how we should represent the "after"? (That is also paper plane related)

Comment: I would just use a single check mark for the success state; if you animate the change, it could look quite neat, I think. There’s also the question of why the message composition window (which, judging by the X in the top left, is a pop-up/overlay in the app?) even remains once the message is sent? If you take a look at how mail apps work, they usually just slide out the entire composition window once the sending succeeds.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This screen is not a modal popup. In fact, it is a full screen activity. Are we not supposed to use an X in this scenario? Also, the check mark is already used in other similar screens (like settings, with an X and a ✓) to indicate the notion of cancel or save. Thus it would not be wise for us to re-use the single check mark to indicate read.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Well, the X makes it look like it can be closed to me, so I’d call that misleading at least. What happens if you click it? Presumably you discard the message you’re writing, but what happens to the window? Empty? Filled with something else? // Check marks are very commonly used to mean both ‘enabled’ and ‘success’; reusing it for that purpose is no problem unless there’s ambiguity as to which meaning is intended. Side note: are we talking about a message _sent_ icon or a message _read_ icon? Those are different things.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for your valuable feedback on the X. As for your side note, I am discussing both the *sent* icon and the *read* icon – since I need advice on both. I think I am going to settle on using a paper plane for *send*, double greyed checkmarks for *sent*, and double green checkmarks for *read*. What do you think about that?

Comment: @AlanSTACK I’d go the more familiar route of single grey check mark for ‘sent’ and double (or just single) green check mark for ‘read’. Double check mark definitely doesn’t say ‘sent’ – if you use it at all, it should be for ‘read’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The reason I don't want to use a single check mark to signify *sent* is because my other screens (such as settings/profile/etc) use single check mark to signify *save*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple, and without any actual text....

...a black, right-pointing, arrow (intuitively meaning "next")...

...... and a grey check mark (intuitively meaning "done")...

[image]

Although.. I'd also maybe want to alter the text at the top and screen that back as well....

[image]

As for "other areas" outlined in the question.. I'd change the "message read" from √√ to simply √. If an "unread" icon is needed, then an empty square or circle.

Comment: A double check mark to mean ‘message read’ is common enough (e.g., WhatsApp uses one check mark for ‘sent’ and two for ‘read’). I wouldn’t necessarily change that. An empty circle is more commonly used to mean ‘offline’, which might prove ambiguous, depending on what the app looks like.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not a WhatsApp user.